# Why hide all headers of the expander does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expander

There are two buttons "ShowAllExpanders" and "HideAllExpanders"

expand all headers work perfectly but collapsing all take just some headers and I have to press the  button "hide all" each time to collapse one by one.

If I bind Tag to the Expander, then I can collapse all expanders but also if I click on just one expander to collapse it, all the rest are collapsed.

ParameterConfigViewList when expanding all headers gives me all headers( count =17) but when I press "hide all" gives me just two( Count=2).

What could I do to collapse every expander apart and also to collapse all if I press button "HideAllExpanders"?

Xaml Code is:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle> 
  <GroupStyle> 
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle> 
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}"> 
        <Setter Property="Template"> 
         <Setter.Value> 
          <ControlTemplate> 
           <Grid> 
             <Expander IsExpanded="True"> 
               <Expander.Style> 
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}"> 
                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" /> 
                 <Setter Property="Template"> 
                  <Setter.Value> 
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}"> 
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> 
                     <DockPanel> 
                       <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding=" 
                         {TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                         ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                         ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"  
                         DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                         FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}"   
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          TemplatedParent}}" 
                         Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" /> 
                         <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" 
                         Visibility="Collapsed" /> 
                      </DockPanel> 
                     </Border> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                     <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true"> 
                      <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" /> 
                      </Trigger> 
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"> 
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" /> 
                     </Trigger> 
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                   </ControlTemplate> 
                  </Setter.Value> 
                 </Setter> 
                </Style> 
               </Expander.Style> 
               <Expander.Header> 
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                 <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
                 <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" /> 
                 <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="configuration" /> 
                </StackPanel> 
              </Expander.Header> 
              <ItemsPresenter /> 
             </Expander> 
            </Grid> 
           </ControlTemplate> 
          </Setter.Value> 
         </Setter> 
        </Style> 
       </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle> 
      </GroupStyle> 
     </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

[Xaml_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylixr.png)

The code in View.xaml.cs:

```
private void HideAllExpanders_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  List<Expander> expander = GetVisualTree<Expander>(ParameterConfigViewList);
    for (int i = 0; i < expander.Count; i++)
      {
         expander[i].Height = 0;
         expander[i].Height = Double.NaN;
         expander[i].IsExpanded = false;
      }
}

private void ShowAllExpanders_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     List<Expander> expander = GetTreeObjects<Expander>(ParameterConfigViewList);
     expander.All(a => a.IsExpanded = true);
}

private List<T> GetTreeObjects<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
     List<T> objects = new List<T>();
     int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if(child != null)
            {
               T requestedType = child as T;
                if(requestedType != null)
                    objects.Add(requestedType);
                    objects.AddRange(this.GetTreeObjects<T>(child));
            }
         }
     return objects;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the XAML part of the code, instead of adding a picture

Comment: I have added the xaml code as you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What could I do to collapse every expander apart and also to collapse
>   all if I press button "HideAllExpanders"?

You may want to implement the following effect. I made a sample depend on the code your provided above.

XAML:

```
   <Grid Margin="10">
    <ListView Name="lvUsers" Margin="0,0,290,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">

                                        <Expander.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <DockPanel>
                                                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0"   Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                     ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"  
                     DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                     FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}"   
                     IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                      TemplatedParent}}" 
                     Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" />
                                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" 
                     Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                                </DockPanel>
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                                                    <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Expander.Style>


                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="HideAllExpanders" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="578,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="ShowAllExpanders" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="578,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" Click="Button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

XAML.CS

```
    private List<T> GetTreeObjects<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null)
            {
                T requestedType = child as T;
                if (requestedType != null)
                    objects.Add(requestedType);
                objects.AddRange(this.GetTreeObjects<T>(child));
            }
        }
        return objects;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ShowAllExpanders
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Expander> expander = GetTreeObjects<Expander>(lvUsers);
        expander.All(a => a.IsExpanded = true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HideAllExpanders
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //List<Expander> expander = GetVisualTree<Expander>(ParameterConfigViewList);
        //for (int i = 0; i < expander.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    expander[i].Height = 0;
        //    expander[i].Height = Double.NaN;
        //    expander[i].IsExpanded = false;
        //}

        //List<Expander> expanderss = FindVisualChildren<Expander>(lvUsers).ToList();

        foreach (Expander tb in FindVisualChildren<Expander>(lvUsers))
        {
            tb.Height = 0;
            tb.Height = Double.NaN;
            tb.IsExpanded = false;
        }

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @Yohann for your work but unfortunately this does not work for me and still gives me the same result maybe my listview is different from yours. My listview has ItemsSource binding the items(parameters)

Comment: the problem was the use of (VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True") in the ListView. Now it work with my code but thanks a lot for your efforts to solve my problem